# Why does stat_density2d() not cover all points?

Tags: r, ggplot2, kernel-density

I am trying to represent distribution and density of a point layer I have. I am using `ggplot` and `stand_density2d()`:

```
p1 <- ggplot()+
  stat_density2d(data=tempSSI,  aes(x=longitude, y=latitude, fill=after_stat(level)), geom="polygon")+ 
 geom_point(data=tempSSI, aes(x=longitude, y=latitude), fill="red", shape=23, alpha=0.8)
```

But when I plot it it is obvious that the contours do not include a big chunk of the points, where the densities are lower. Can I adjust this somehow?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solved by using the `bins=` argument. Increasing the number of bins increases the number of the contours which encompass then more points.

```
p1 <- ggplot(data=tempMSI,aes(longitude,latitude))   + 
  stat_density2d(data=tempMSI,aes(fill=..level..,alpha=..level..),bins=25,geom='polygon',colour='black') + 
  scale_fill_continuous(low="sienna1",high="sienna4")+ geom_point()
p1`
```

[image]

Comment: Glad it's solved - could you please provide a bit more detail (ideally the final code and resulting image) to help those who come after?

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen just updated the answer

Comment: This is a very old-fashioned way to create filled contours in ggplot. There has been `geom_density2d_filled` for a number of years now. By default, this will cover the whole plane. If you want, you can set breaks and have a threshold below which nothing is drawn.